# create a hash of occurrences in an array with map

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I seem to recall that there was a "clever" way to create a hash from an array with Perl with `map` such that the keys are the elements of the the array and the values are the number of times the element appears. Something like this, although this does not work:

```
$ perl -e '@a = ('a','a','b','c'); %h = map { $_ => $_ + 1  } @a ; foreach $k (keys (%h)) { print "$k -> $h{$k}\n"}'
c -> 1
b -> 1
a -> 2
$
```

Am I imagining things? How can I do this?

Comment: Be careful with the single quotes inside one-liners. If you had a string with a space or a comma or something like that when initializing `@a`, this wouldn't work. (eg, `@a = ('a', 'b', 'c d')` would not work)

Comment: What's wrong with `for(qw/a b a c/){$h{$_}++}`?

Comment: Nothing, just looking for Mr. Tim Toady.

Comment: I'm vaguely recalling a `map..while` idiom, which might be what you're remembering. However, it isn't appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write `map {$h{$_}++} @a` ignoring its return value, but  why would you do this?  `for (@a){$h{$_}++}` is easy enough to type.

So why would you *not* do it?

`map` is meant for transforming lists. It takes an input list and generates an output list. It can confuse a reader if you use it in a different way using side effect instead of output.

Also, although map is optimized to not create the output list when called in void context, it is slower:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Benchmark qw/cmpthese/;
my @in = map {chr(int(rand(127)+1))} 1..10000;

my %out;
cmpthese(10000,
         {stmtfor => sub{%out = (); $out{$_}++ for @in},
          voidmap => sub{%out = (); map {$out{$_}++} @in;},
          }
     );

__END__

          Rate voidmap stmtfor
voidmap 2075/s      --    -17%
stmtfor 2513/s     21%      --
```

Comment: Because I'm not a Python programmer ;-) This does seem to be the thing I was remembering though. 

```
$ perl -e '@a = ('a','a','b','c'); map { $h{$_}++ } @a ; foreach $k (keys (%h)) { print "$k -> $h{$k}\n"}'
b -> 1
c -> 1
a -> 2
$
```

Comment: @PaulD "_why would you do this_"  --- means that it's just not good practice, using a function which has its main point in returning (`map` builds and returns a list corresponding to its input list, that's what it is for) for its side effects.  And even though we do indeed often do more convoluted, and perhaps less conforming, things in Perl than in Python we do try to stay on the good side of general programming practices :)

Comment: Ah, I see the point now. The man page for map is not something I have memorized.

Comment: Intrestingly i found, that statement modifier for is faster than a for loop.

Comment: *But also important, it does more work than needed building the output list and throwing it away* I'm not sure which version of Perl you're using, but since Perl 5.8.1 (in 2003), `map` has been context sensitive and it no longer constructs the output list when called in void context. See [perldelta581](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl581delta.pod#Miscellaneous-Enhancements).

Comment: @Dave Cross that is interesting. Does the point that it is slower hold or did I overlook something in the Benchmark?

Comment: @clamp: Your benchmark seems fine to me. Perhaps `for` is just inherently faster.

Comment: @clamp A loop in a postifix syntax (so as a "statement-modifier") doesn't have its own scope (and cannot have a topicalizer) so right there there's a tad bit less work to do. There are I think a few other tweaks as well. And that's in comparison with a normal `for` loop, and I can imagine that `map` has yet a little more overhead. Now, I wouldn't have expected quite 20%...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but you can easily do that with a `for` rather than a `map`:

```
$ perl -e '@a = ('a','a','b','c'); $h{$_}++ for @a; foreach $k (keys (%h)) { print "$k -> $h{$k}\n"}'
c -> 1
b -> 1
a -> 2
```

Comment: That is nice and Perlish alternative.

Comment: Since you're already using the "postfix" notation ([Statement Modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers)) why not print with it as well: `print "$_ => $h{$_}\n" for keys %h;`.  Goes along nicely with the first one (and saves a few keystrokes and some mental parsing of a `for`-loop)

Comment: @zdim Sure, why not. I don't think this makes the code simpler though, especially for a beginner (OP mentioned that they are not very familiar with Perl). For us, statement modifiers are natural and simple, but I've heard countless people laughing at Perl for this feature, and I know of plenty of people that find them hard to read. Mixing statements modifiers and compound statements like I do in my answer might be seen as lacking consistency though.

Comment: "_don't think this makes the code simpler_" -- sure, that postfix notation isn't the first thing to do with a loop (to say the least); my comment wasn't meant to be criticism (nor to suggest that postfix is better). I just meant to bring that up since it's not shown anywhere on the page (for printing the hash), and your answer nicely does use postfix in the first example.  Btw, that "reversed" syntax (expression then range) isn't unusual; for one, it's everywhere in Python.